# member show profile picture wont show

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command who shows the specified user's profile picture. no errors it just doesn't work.

**code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def pfp(ctx, *,member : discord.Member):

    embed = discord.Embed(colour = random.choice(mycolor))

    mylist1 = ["What a creep",
               "stalker"]

    embed.set_author(name=f"{random.choice(mylist1)}")

    embed.set_image(url=ctx.member.avatar_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The code should be like this.**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def pfp(ctx, *,member : discord.Member):

    embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Red())

    embed.set_image(url='{}'.format(member.avatar_url))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error might come from this line :

```py
embed.set_image(url=ctx.member.avatar_url)
```

[`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) objects don't have any `question` attribute. If you want the command author's profile picture :

```py
async def pfp(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    (...)
    embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
    (...)
```

Also, typing `question = discord.Member` is useless, it would just asign the `Member` class to your `question` variable.
I've also noticed that `mycolor` seems undefined.

Comment: ctx.author.avatar_url would show the image of the person who sent the URL but I want it show who they mention like .pfp @example#0001

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm assuming that it just doesn't send a message. I think that you want `@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=[])` instead of `@client.command()`. `pass_context` makes it assign ctx.

Comment: In the lastest versions of `discord.py`, `pass_context` isn't necessary

Comment: That would not make any sense would it-